# CakePHP does not fetch a new field created on a database view

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-2.7

I've had to add the field *cpf_formatado* to my database view (SQL Server) *vwComissionarios*. But the CakePHP model does not fetch this new field, and this is driving me crazy.

This print shows that the field was correctly created on the database view:

[image]

But, for some reason, CakePHP does not fetch the field, and I'm using the same query. This is a test:

```
public function infoGestor($id = null){
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->loadModel('Comissionario');
        debug($this->Comissionario->query("select cpf_formatado from vwcomissionarios")); die();
}
```

[image]

Finally, this is the Comissionario model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Comissionario Model
 *
 */
class Comissionario extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'vwComissionarios';

/**
 * Primary key field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'nome';

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */

    public $hasMany = array(
        'VwComissionarioContato' => array('className' => 'VwComissionarioContato',
            'foreignKey' => 'comissionarios_id',
            'conditions' => array(),
            'fields' => array(),
            'order' => '',
        ),
        'ComissionarioBanco' => array('className' => 'ComissionarioBanco',
            'foreignKey' => 'comissionarios_id',
            'conditions' => array(),
            'fields' => array(),
            'order' => '',
        ),      
    );
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `query()` rather than a `find()` method to retrieve data from the database?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja As I said, this was just a test.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the CakePHP cache?

Comment: @PradeepSanjaya that won't work for CakePHP 2.7!

Comment: If your app configured to use file cache in default file cache, try removing cache files created in cache/models filder. cd app/tmp/cache/models && rm -f cake_*

Comment: @PradeepSanjaya I'm googling about, and it seems this just work in CakePHP 3.0.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja yes, I deleted all app\tmp\cache content, but this did not work too.

Comment: @PradeepSanjaya I deleted all app\tmp\cache content, but this did not work too

Comment: I think cake doesn't work well with SQL views... According to this [line](http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/source-class-Sqlserver.html#177). You should extend Sqlserver datasource to include views or just use tables and create associations to fetch your data.

Comment: @skywalker this is a good point. I executed the query of this line and it fetchs the views too. So, I think the problem is with this [line](http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/source-class-Sqlserver.html#213). I have just to debug this.